# VBA: Trim along column with several values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trim a column with a large amount of rows. First of all I tried with a "For each", but it takes so much time. Then I tried with a code like this:

```
Sub TrimTest()

Dim rangeTrim As Range

  Set rangeTrim = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Column("A:A")
    rangeTrim.Value = Application.Trim(rangeTrim.Value)


End Sub
```

In spite of being so fast, it only works sometimes. It bugs with Run-time error '1004' (Application-defined or object-defined error) and I have to run the macro again.

Is there any other method to trim the whole column?

Comment: Why trim a million rows?

Comment: What does "it bugs" mean exactly? Are you getting any particular specific error? `rangeTrim.Value` will be a 2D variant array, not sure `Application.Trim` handles that - if it doesn't, then the code can't be working "sometimes". If there's no `Book1` or `Sheet1`, then you're getting error 9. Please [edit] your question to include more information about the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your observations. It stops on line "rangeTrim.Value = Application.Trim(rangeTrim.Value)" and ir shows error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed up processing each cell by doing it in a VBA array.
I do not believe you can apply `WorksheetFunction.Trim` to an array of cells.

so:

```
Sub trimColumn(WS As Worksheet, Optional colNum As Long = 1)
    Dim v As Variant, I As Long, R As Range

With WS
    Set R = Range(.Cells(1, colNum), .Cells(.Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp))
End With

v = R

For I = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    v(I, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(v(I, 1))
Next I

R = v

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## TRIM Column

**Test**

I tested both solutions on columns with a million string values using MicroTimer. There was a slightly better (1-2%) performance by the array version. Trim used in this way will not raise an error if there is an error value, a number or a formula. Any formulas will be lost, only the values will be written back to the sheet. The time needed to trim a million string values was about 3.5 seconds on my computer.

**Usage: Call from another Sub Examples**

```
trimColumnA Sheet1, "A", 2
trimColumnA Sheet2, 2
trimColumnA Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), "H"
```

**The Code**

```
Sub trimColumnA(Sheet As Worksheet, trimColumn As Variant, _
  Optional FirstRow As Long = 1)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim vnt As Variant

    With Sheet
        ' Define last cell range containing a value.
        Set rng = .Columns(trimColumn).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
          Searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        ' Define Trim Range.
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, trimColumn), rng)
        vnt = rng
        rng.Value = Application.Trim(vnt)
    End With

End Sub

Sub trimColumnR(Sheet As Worksheet, trimColumn As Variant, _
  Optional FirstRow As Long = 1)

    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheet
        ' Define last cell range containing a value.
        Set rng = .Columns(trimColumn).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
          Searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        ' Define Trim Range.
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, trimColumn), rng)
    End With

    rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng.Value)

End Sub
```